# How can I make dropdown menu main item stay in position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I've built a menu with Superfish v1.4.8. Everything is fine but I need to show menu item's hover state when mouse is over its drop-down items. In case I want "Ürünler" to be at its hover state when it's dropdown menu is open.

Site can be seen [here](http://demo.ozkaynakmakina.com.tr/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your CSS?

```
.sfHover .main {background-position: -114px -45px;}
```

Comment: Your code is right but it does not work properly because probably mouse out style overrides it. When I put border:1px solid red just for test it's working as needed.

Comment: go back up in the dom one more level to overpower the inheritance. 
find its parent and for example if it has an id then go like:

#parentID .sfHover .main {...}